# How to convert json array to a dictionary that also contains duplicate keys?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, api

I am trying to convert my json array into key/value pairs in a Dictionary but I keep getting my Keys and Values as null.

```
Exception : System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key'
```

I am trying to get them as

```
"Key" : Value
"Key" : Value
```

Here is the Json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "David",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "John",
    "type": 0,
  }
]
```

I have tried the following

```
var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>(jsonString).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Comment: You should first serialize it to array of objects and then you can convert to dictionary by selecting which property to be used as key and which to be used as value.

Comment: What is supposed to be the key and what's the value?

Comment: Your json is just a regular array

Answer (score 1):

**Given**

```
public class MyArray    {
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public int type { get; set; } 

}

public class SomeFunkyRoot    {
    public List<MyArray> MyArray { get; set; } 

}
```

**To deserialise to a dictionary**

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeFunkyRoot>(jsonString);

// returns Dictionary<int,MyArray>
var dict root.MyArray
             .ToDictionary(x => x.id);
```

**If you have duplicate ids**

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeFunkyRoot>(jsonString);

// returns Dictionary<int,List<MyArray>>
var dict = root.MyArray
              .GroupBy(x => x.id)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());

// or you could use a lookup
// returns ILookup<int,MyArray>
var lookup = root.MyArray
                 .ToLookup(x => x.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheGeneral answer is great. Anyway I wanted to write other version.

```
var anonymousType = new[] { new { id = 0, name = "", type = 0 } };
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anonymousType);
var dict = data.GroupBy(x => x.id).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: This will throw for duplicate keys.